# Dependency not found after compiling

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use [JByteMod](https://github.com/GraxCode/JByteMod-Beta) and I tried using the most up to date release version but when I run it, I get an error saying

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.alee.utils.ProprietaryUtils - java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2149)
        at com.alee.utils.ReflectUtils.getStaticFieldValue(ReflectUtils.java:440)
        at com.alee.utils.ProprietaryUtils.setupUIDefaults(ProprietaryUtils.java:103)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(WebLookAndFeel.java:537)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:153)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:593)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:639)
        at com.alee.utils.LafUtils.setupLookAndFeelSafely(LafUtils.java:1557)
        at com.alee.utils.LafUtils.setupLookAndFeelSafely(LafUtils.java:1544)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:939)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:927)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.utils.gui.LookUtils.setLAF(LookUtils.java:15)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod$1.run(JByteMod.java:166)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
[AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.alee.utils.XmlUtils - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:496)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:465)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:411)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:378)
        at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.initializeXStream(XmlUtils.java:94)
        at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.getXStream(XmlUtils.java:81)
        at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.processAnnotations(XmlUtils.java:148)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel$2.propertyChange(WebLookAndFeel.java:856)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:343)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(SwingPropertyChangeSupport.java:93)
        at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:268)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:602)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:639)
        at com.alee.utils.LafUtils.setupLookAndFeelSafely(LafUtils.java:1557)
        at com.alee.utils.LafUtils.setupLookAndFeelSafely(LafUtils.java:1544)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:939)
        at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:927)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.utils.gui.LookUtils.setLAF(LookUtils.java:15)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod$1.run(JByteMod.java:166)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5a61f5df
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
        ... 35 more
```

I tried 3 other forks and I always receive a smiliar error. I asked others and they said it works fine for them. I then decided to clone the repo and try to manually compile it but I cant seem to find this dependency.

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.weblaf</groupId>
         <artifactId>weblaf</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
```

I tried these which seemed close and did not cause errors in maven but I would still get errors inside of inteillJ such as with this line `WebButton.createIconWebButton(i, StyleConstants.smallRound, true);`

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.weblookandfeel</groupId>
         <artifactId>weblaf-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.weblookandfeel</groupId>
         <artifactId>weblaf-ui</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.weblookandfeel</groupId>
         <artifactId>weblaf-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
```

Even with the other forks when I cloned them and who compile correctly (so all dependencies worked from the start) I would still get an error coming from the same thing when I attempt to run it.

```
C:\Users\yozma\Desktop\JByte>java -jar JByteMod-Remastered-2.1.4.jar
[17:19:10] [INFO] Reading Language XML..
[17:19:10] [INFO] Successfully loaded 215 local resources and 215 default resources
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/alee/laf/WebLookAndFeel
        at me.grax.jbytemod.res.LanguageRes.fixUnicodeSupport(LanguageRes.java:33)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.res.LanguageRes.<init>(LanguageRes.java:27)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod.initialize(JByteMod.java:173)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod.main(JByteMod.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Really, I am not too sure what this alee.laf thing is but it appears to be used in making the ui but I have no idea why its causing an error in every attempt.

Edit: After adding this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mathiasritter</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblaf-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

I now get a new error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/alee/extended/breadcrumb/WebBreadcrumbToggleButton
        at me.grax.jbytemod.ui.MyTabbedPane.<init>(MyTabbedPane.java:21)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.ui.MySplitPane.<init>(MySplitPane.java:13)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod.<init>(JByteMod.java:138)
        at me.grax.jbytemod.JByteMod$2.run(JByteMod.java:231)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alee.extended.breadcrumb.WebBreadcrumbToggleButton
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: Java modules have a namespace structure, kind of the reverse of web domain names, going from generic to specific.  The module you need is `com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel`.  I don't know where `com.weblookandfeel` came from.

Comment: @TimRoberts That makes sense I am not sure why I did not get any errors while compiling but that worked but I know get a new error that has to do with same sort of dependency

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @Dale Nope check the edit